# How can I view in VS2015 output window a List<string>?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been using this as a way to view output?

```
  Debug.WriteLine("abc");
```

Now I would like to sent the output of this:

```
  Debug.WriteLine(result.examples);
```

Where examples is a List

But I understand that Debug.Writeline accepts only a string

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a logging framework, so that you could redirect output to the console, debug or streams as needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `string.Join` to form a `,`(or any separator) separated `string`

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result.examples));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.examples));
```

Comment: `String.Join` works with enumerables, there's no need to call `ToArray`